# How can I center images and text in this search autocomplete form?

Tags: html, css

[Product search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZxj6.png)

I would like to center these product images & descriptions in the search form.
I think I've caused my issue with having left & right results as per HTML below.
But I may be wrong. I just want to neaten it up a little bit.
Having it to the left looks odd.

I'm kind of at the limit of my simple knowledge here.
I'm sorry if this is a basic question.

HTML

```
  <span id="inline-search-results" class="hide-in-mobile-menu inline-search-results" style="display: inline;"><div class="grid12-12 new-advanced-search-box" id="new-advanced-search-box">
        <div class="grid12-4 results-left">
        <ul class="terms">
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avensynt1152"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nsynt1152</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avensynt1151"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nsynt1151</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avensynt1150"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nsynt1150</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avensynt1156"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nsynt1156</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avensynt1145"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nsynt1145</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avensynt1155"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nsynt1155</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avensynt1154"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nsynt1154</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avenue"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nue</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avensynt1153"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nsynt1153</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avensynt1149"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nsynt1149</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avensynt1148"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nsynt1148</a>
                </li>
                                <li>
                    <a href="/product_search/?q=avensynt1157"><span class="highlight">ave</span>nsynt1157</a>
                </li>
                        </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="grid12-8 results-right">
        <div class="products">
            <ul>
                                        <li class="grid12-4 grow">
                        <a title="Avenue Rayne 1150" href="/solution-dyed-nylon-carpets/avenue/avensynt1150-avenue-rayne-1150/">
                            <div class="product-img">
                                <img class="inline-search-img " src="https://cdn-5c84bc36-b681cbc1.mysagestore.com/d2dffd71ca1f290f12a2a3d9bf2343e7/contents/AVENSYNT1150/thumbnail/big_AVENSYNT1150.jpg" alt="Avenue Rayne 1150">
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-desc"><span class="highlight">Ave</span>nue Rayne 1150</div>
                            <div class="product-code"><span class="highlight">AVE</span>NSYNT1150ALIAS</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="grid12-4 grow">
                        <a title="Avenue Milton 1149" href="/solution-dyed-nylon-carpets/avenue/avensynt1149-avenue-milton-1149/">
                            <div class="product-img">
                                <img class="inline-search-img " src="https://cdn-5c84bc36-b681cbc1.mysagestore.com/d2dffd71ca1f290f12a2a3d9bf2343e7/contents/AVENSYNT1149/thumbnail/big_AVENSYNT1149.jpg" alt="Avenue Milton 1149">
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-desc"><span class="highlight">Ave</span>nue Milton 1149</div>
                            <div class="product-code"><span class="highlight">AVE</span>NSYNT1149ALIAS</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="grid12-4 grow">
                        <a title="Avenue Morland 1148" href="/solution-dyed-nylon-carpets/avenue/avensynt1148-avenue-morland-1148/">
                            <div class="product-img">
                                <img class="inline-search-img " src="https://cdn-5c84bc36-b681cbc1.mysagestore.com/d2dffd71ca1f290f12a2a3d9bf2343e7/contents/AVENSYNT1148/thumbnail/big_AVENSYNT1148.jpg" alt="Avenue Morland 1148">
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-desc"><span class="highlight">Ave</span>nue Morland 1148</div>
                            <div class="product-code"><span class="highlight">AVE</span>NSYNT1148ALIAS</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="grid12-4 grow">
                        <a title="Avenue Cudmore 1154" href="/solution-dyed-nylon-carpets/avenue/avensynt1154-avenue-cudmore-1154/">
                            <div class="product-img">
                                <img class="inline-search-img " src="https://cdn-5c84bc36-b681cbc1.mysagestore.com/d2dffd71ca1f290f12a2a3d9bf2343e7/contents/AVENSYNT1154/thumbnail/big_AVENSYNT1154.jpg" alt="Avenue Cudmore 1154">
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-desc"><span class="highlight">Ave</span>nue Cudmore 1154</div>
                            <div class="product-code"><span class="highlight">AVE</span>NSYNT1154ALIAS</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="grid12-4 grow">
                        <a title="Autumn Mist Mistflower 1157" href="/solution-dyed-nylon-carpets/avenue/avensynt1157-avenue-annesley-1157/">
                            <div class="product-img">
                                <img class="inline-search-img " src="https://cdn-5c84bc36-b681cbc1.mysagestore.com/d2dffd71ca1f290f12a2a3d9bf2343e7/contents/AVENSYNT1157/thumbnail/big_AVENSYNT1157.jpg" alt="Autumn Mist Mistflower 1157">
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-desc">Autumn Mist Mistflower 1157</div>
                            <div class="product-code">AUTUSYNT1157ALIAS</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                        <li class="grid12-4 grow">
                        <a title="Avenue Sherwood 1151" href="/solution-dyed-nylon-carpets/avenue/avensynt1151-avenue-sherwood-1151/">
                            <div class="product-img">
                                <img class="inline-search-img " src="https://cdn-5c84bc36-b681cbc1.mysagestore.com/d2dffd71ca1f290f12a2a3d9bf2343e7/contents/AVENSYNT1151/thumbnail/big_AVENSYNT1151.jpg" alt="Avenue Sherwood 1151">
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-desc"><span class="highlight">Ave</span>nue Sherwood 1151</div>
                            <div class="product-code"><span class="highlight">AVE</span>NSYNT1151ALIAS</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    element.style {
    display: inline; }
   @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
#inline-search-results {
    width: 100%; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 960px)
#inline-search-results {
    width: 370px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px)
#inline-search-results {
    width: 590px;
}

#inline-search-results {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px silver;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px silver;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2001;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
} 

.grid-col2-main, .grid-col2-sidebar, .grid-full, .grid12-1, .grid12-10, .grid12-11, .grid12-12, .grid12-2, .grid12-3, .grid12-4, .grid12-5, .grid12-6, .grid12-7, .grid12-8, .grid12-9 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

Comment: can you give us more information it would be helpful if you can post the code in snippet area

Answer (score 0):

```
**Add display flex property and align-items center**



 #inline-search-results {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
        border: 1px solid silver;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px silver;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px silver;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 2001;
        top: 35px;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items:center;
        justify-content:center
         
    }
```

Comment: That hasn't changed anything unfortunately